# ERROR "execution reverted: AssetContractShared#creatorOnly: ONLY_CREATOR_ALLOWED"

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, error, bug

I am doing a two step minting process.

1. user will setApprovalForAll for a new contract to transfer old tokens
2. user will burn old tokens and mint new ones from the new contract

Burn and mint function below:

```
function BurnBabyBurn() 
    public
  {

    require(burnIsActive, "burn must be active to mint Final");
    require(BurnContract(piecesAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender, burnPieceIds[0]) > 0, "Must 
    have a balance for each piece");

    BurnContract(piecesAddress).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, to, burnPieceIds[0], 
     burnPieceAmounts[0], "");

    _mint(msg.sender, finalPieceId, 1, "");
  }
```

When I run this on Mumbai everything works as expected. When I switch to matic mainnet I start to receive this error

"execution reverted: AssetContractShared#creatorOnly: ONLY_CREATOR_ALLOWED"

The tokens we are burning come from the opensea collectibles contract(0x2953399124F0cBB46d2CbACD8A89cF0599974963). Inside of that contract there is a modifier

```
/**
 * @dev Require msg.sender to be the creator of the token id
 */
modifier creatorOnly(uint256 _id) {
    require(
        _isCreatorOrProxy(_id, _msgSender()),
        "AssetContractShared#creatorOnly: ONLY_CREATORALLOWED"
    );
    ;
}
```

But this is where I am very confused as the modifier is only added to these functions:
Mint, setURI, setPermanentURI, setCreator

Im not calling any of these functions. any idea why this could be happening?

Interface used above:

```
interface BurnContract {
   function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external;
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution, got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the Opensea contract, and, while I am not sure if this code is the one running the Opensea Storefront, the **error message matches**.

Let's have a look at the overriding safeTransformFrom function:

```
function safeTransferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _id,
    uint256 _amount,
    bytes memory _data
) public override {
    uint256 mintedBalance = super.balanceOf(_from, _id);
    if (mintedBalance < _amount) {
        // Only mint what _from doesn't already have
        mint(_to, _id, _amount - mintedBalance, _data);
        if (mintedBalance > 0) {
            super.safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _id, mintedBalance, _data);
        }
    } else {
        super.safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _id, _amount, _data);
    }
}
```

Found here https://polygonscan.com/address/0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963#code (line 2141).

If you are calling the function as an address that has been approved, you actually don't own the token, so the balanceOf will return a value of 0, which will always be smaller than the _amount.
So, the minting function is called. And that's where you have the modifier that leads to the error.

Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this. Passing a 0 _amount won't do the trick, because the balance of the token will remain unchanged.

**UPDATE**

I might have found a way:

- test the balance of the token
- if it has no balance, mint it first (from the transferring account)
- then you can setApprovalForAll
- then the transfer should work

Here is the transfer transaction:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x117cbf460dc1f340db4b63d61850fc82a075222cd7b0fc9a4c677665ac8d17d7

And here was the mint:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x95260c508d69f35d1b3566db44faacc1373d3d3e1bf6d74deb39f6e0c04e2f19

And here the setApprovalForAll:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xf750f7af34fb402d58eafc3c557cc3dec395ac18a57b7f1597c9deba37b2bafe

Please note that I haven't tested if minting into the target address would also work.